# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_visual_analysis'

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-9990fa3e94d0> in <module>
----> 1 from pandas_visual_analysis import VisualAnalysis
      2 VisualAnalysis(Data)
```

How to solve this error, please, Help me ...

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the package:

```
pip install pandas-visual-analysis
```

See [the project's PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-visual-analysis/).